# Unhandled exception has occured in the application vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Ok, so my **code** look like the following.

```
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("E:/Med/Dra.txt", False)
    file.WriteLine(NameBasic)
    file.WriteLine(LastBasic)
    file.WriteLine(PhoneBasic)
    file.Close();
```

All those are variables that I have set for text boxes. This is `OnbuttonClick(...`

Now for my `onload` I take the info out of the notepad, Here is the **code**,

```
    Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader
    read = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("E:/Med/Dra.txt")
    lblNameBasic.Text = read.ReadLine
    lblLastBasic.Text = read.ReadLine
    lblPhoneBasic.Text = read.ReadLine
    read.Close();
```

I have placed the notepad(txt file) inside a flashdrive folder named `med`
I got the saving info to work and load, so I took the flashdrive to another computer, I got this nasty error, talking about the `System.IO` and all this other stuff.

It then prompts me, would you like to continue with errors, or quit.
I click `continue` than all the saved data does not load. Am I doing something wrong here??

Also sorry for alot of questions today. (The .exe is in the flashdrive, med folder aswell).

Comment: My bet is that when you plug the drive into a different computer, it is not `E:`.

Comment: Yeah it shows that it is J, How could I make it a universal thing? @Plutonix

Comment: Use an OpenFileDialog and browse to your file to get the location, and pass that location into the OpenTextFileReader.

Comment: I dont understand what that is? @Shar1er80

Comment: Research (Google) goes a long way

Comment: @Shar1er80 I did research it, and it came up as, it opens up a file directory, and than you select the file, and that is not what I am looking for. Maybe something that searches for the file name within the folder it is in? Like CurDir but It does not work..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your path is incorrect - `E:/Med/Dra.txt` should be `E:\Med\Dra.txt`. And here how you use open file dialog  - this is just basis, you need to take care of error handling, etc.

```
Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 

If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 

    Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)           

End If
```

I think, main reason why you had errors is because incorrect path. You can also check if path exists

```
If Not File.Exists("E:\Med\Dra.txt") Then 
    MessageBox.Show("There is no such file")
    Exit Sub
End If
' Code to open non existing file will be skipped
```